# converting a number to set range of numbers?

Tags: python, numbers

so far I have this

```
for letter in name:
    number = ord(letter) - 96
    if number>=1 and number<=9:
        output.append(number)
    else:
        #change value to corresponding numeric value?
```

I am supposed to convert the letters in a name to corresponding numbers in numerology values
http://m.wikihow.com/Calculate-Your-Name-Number-in-Numerology
right now it outputs the letter number for only the first 9 letters of the alphabet and leaves out the values for any letter past i.

Comment: Mathematically you should be able to accomplish this using a modulo (`%`) operator. I.E. `10 % 9 == 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of each letter can be concisely written as `(ord(letter) - 97)%9 + 1`. The full code would then be:

```
for letter in name:
    number = (ord(letter) - 97)%9 + 1
    output.append(number)
```

Comment: That helped a bunch, I was thinking too hard about it. Thanks!